# create gatsby-node pages based on a graphql query

Tags: javascript, graphql, content-management-system, gatsby

I want to `createPage` based on some queries I am using , this is my query in my `gatsby-node.js` :

```
{
      allPrismicLastPosts {
        nodes {
          data {
            blogs {
              blog {
                document {
                  ... on PrismicBlog {
                    uid
                  }
                  ... on PrismicCulture {
                    uid
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      allPrismicMainBlogs {
        nodes {
          data {
            blogs {
              blog {
                document {
                  ... on PrismicBlogMain {
                    uid
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

what I want from this query is the `uid` field ,
and Since this query returns this JSON format :

```
allPrismicMainBlogs": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "data": {
            "blogs": [
              {
                "blog": {
                  "document": {
                    "uid": "main02",
                     .
                     .
                     .
}
```

I've tried this to fetch the `uid` :

```
  postPages.data.allPrismicLastPosts.nodes.forEach((page) => {
    page.data.blogs.forEach((article)=>
    {
      createPage({
        path: article.blog.document.data.uid,
        component: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/post.js'),
        context: {
          id: page.id,
        },
      })
    }
    )
  })
```

I cannot get the `uid` because I am using `allPrismicLastPosts` but instead I want all the queries , so how can I fix this to display all the `uid`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access directly to:

```
article.blog.document.uid
```

Applied to your code:

```
postPages.data.allPrismicLastPosts.nodes.forEach((page) => {
  page.data.blogs.forEach((article) => {
    createPage({
      path: article.blog.document.uid,
      component: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/templates/post.js"),
      context: {
        id: page.id,
      },
    });
  });
});
```